# Cannot connect to database remotely (not even locally when using ip address)

Tags: oracle, listener

I can login using this command:
`sqlplus test/test@127.0.0.1:1521/local`
But not this one: (where 192.168.0.240) is my IP
`sqlplus test/test@192.168.0.240:1521/local`

I am absolutely sure that my ip address (server's adress) is `192.168.0.240`. So why am I getting the following error? `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`

I get a connection timeout when trying to connect from other computers.

`lsnrctl status`gives me the following:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                23-OCT-2013 15:27:35
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 37 min. 20 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\pc2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\liste
ner.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\pc2\diag\tnslsnr\pc2-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "local", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "localXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "local", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
--> it's only listening on 127.0.0.1. Check your C:\app\pc2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\liste
ner.ora

edit the host = <ip> part or add one. and do lsnrctl reload

Comment: i edited the settings and added another host 192.168.0.240 i can now connect using that address  but only from the sever, not other machines on the same subnet. Ping succeeds but db connection fails.

Comment: it was a firewall issue. I thought the port should be open by default on private networks, or automatically enabled by the installer (like most other programs). Apparently it was being blocked, and I never got a notification from windows firewall. What a waste of time!

Comment: You mean security is a waste of time? :P GG

Comment: No, I'm just saying it took me much more time than it should have. Maybe I ignored the firewall dialog (the one with keep blocking/unblock buttons) when it showed up the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
```

You have the localhost ip in the listener.ora (127.0.0.1), change this or add another line with the NIC ip.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, its an issue with the firewall. Please make sure that your firewall is set to Off and then try to reconnect from another computer. I had the same problem and resolved it by doing the same.

Comment: this question already has an accepted answer and it was not firewall related

Comment: This helped me, I was debugging why suddenly oracle stopped accepting remote connections. After reading this comment I asked my colleague and It turned out my colleague modified the security group assigned the VM.